# Non Repeating Numbers

Tags: matlab, unique

I am using chaos function to create a random number matrix(2d)in matlab and used these numbers for index.I want combination of the two numbers are non repeating.

```
a=[25,45;  25,30;  30,45;  25,45]
```

Expected result:

```
b=[25,45;25,30;30,45]
```

How can I do that using MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `unique` command with the `'rows'` argument

```
b = unique( a, 'rows' )
```

### **EDIT:** preserving order of unique rows

As described in comments, the result `b` should maintain the same order of unique rows as in `a`.
How to do that?

- For recent releases it is not a problem, simply use `'stable'` argument

  ```
  >> b = unique( a, 'rows', 'stable' );
  ```
- It is a bit more tricky for older version.

  ```
  >> [ignore, ia, ib] = unique( a, 'rows', 'first' );
  >> b = a( sort(ia), : )
  ```

Comment: Hi.I used this code the result was 25    30
    25    45
    30    45 not 25,45;25,30;30,45. how this code work ?

Comment: @saba2085 - isn't it the result you wanted? are you troubled by the fact that the order of rows was changed?

Comment: read the [manual on `unique`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html). Especially the part on `setOrder` parameter.

Comment: I have 2007 Version of matlab.These setOrder parameters is only in 2013 Version of matlab?